# Create shortcut to Content Files in File System's Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

In File System panel of Visual Studio's Setup Project, we can create a shortcut to Primary Output, but how can we create a shortcut to Content Files?

For example: I added a Log.txt file as a Content Files, and I want to create a shortcut to that file.

I've been looking for it but I got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use either Primary Output or Content Files. You can just drag the individual files (or add them in the IDE) into the required folder in the File System view. So, for your text file, just add it into (say) the CommonAppData or User's Personal Data folder, then you can right-click on the text file, create shortcut and drag the shortcut to User's Dektop or wherever you want it.